# What is the format for an android intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-contentprovider

I'd like to know what is the format for an android intent. IE, what should I pass to the method :

> getBaseContext().startService(Intent);

If I want to pass this:

> android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI

can i? What would be the format.

Can someone give a good explanation of how to use Intents, and how to use it on Service implementation, like, `startService()`, or `onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to call a new Activity this is the method.

startActivity(new Intent(this, MYACtivityClass.class));

If you want to pass values into the Activity, you need to create a Bundle

> Intent a = new Intent(this,
>   MYACtivityClass.class); Bundle b = new
>   Bundle(); b.putBoolean("test", true);
>   a.putExtra("myBundle", b);
>   startActivity(a);