# Click list item will move into another activity class

Tags: android, android-intent

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private Menu addMenuButton;  
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainact);
    public void onPopup(View view)
{
    PopupMenu menu=new PopupMenu(this,view);
    menu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1,menu.getMenu());
    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
        {
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    item.getTitle()+"Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            //Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourSpotActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent2);


    toast.show();
    return true;
        }
    });
    menu.show();

} }
```

please tell the solution to move into another activity when click on the item list.
I am new to program. This is my first program. Try to explain in depth. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) are used to move from one activity to another.

An Intent is basically a message to say you did or want something to happen. Depending on the intent, apps or the OS might be listening for it and will react accordingly.

**Explicit intent**

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourSpotActivity.class);
startActivity(intent2);
```

**Remember** to add your activity in your **AndroidManifest**

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.abc.YourActivity" > </activity>
```

This will call YourSpotActivity i.e this activity will be visible and MainActivity will remain on stack and when you press back button MainActivity will be visible again

- In an **Explicit intent**, you specify the activity that is required to respond to the intent. In other words, you explicitly designate the target component.
- In an **Implicit intent** , you just declare an intent and leave it to the android platform to find an activity that can respond to the intent.

**Related Links:**

[What is an Intent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578051/what-is-intent-in-android)

[What is the format for an android intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513207/what-is-the-format-for-an-android-intent?rq=1)

[Intent Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/)

**P.S**- why have you commented the intent code ?? Uncomment it and your code will work

Comment: did you uncommented this part //Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourSpotActivity.class);
//startActivity(intent2);  First you accepted the answer than you unaccepted it and then you accepted some other answer !! I think you should learn to run your code successfully using a answer and then only accept it .

Comment: ok ok i accept ur explanation.. i am new to this site.. so i was click both of ur answers correct.. now only i know it was choose only one..

Answer (score 0):

use the below code in onMenuItemClick block

```
startActivity(new Intent(Current_class.this,Destination.class));
```

it start navigation to destination class.

Comment: i am working in map program.. while click the list item named map, is was display toast message only. not go to map activity..

Answer (score 0):

Your commented code should work if you enable it. Is it not working?

```
//Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourSpotActivity.class);
//startActivity(intent2);
```

You need to add this new activity `YourSpotActivity` in your AndroidManifest.xml file for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment your code and add yourspotactivity in your Android Manifest File , this will solve your issue .